# How many Kbs/Mbs/Gbs of data can Android Room database store?

Tags: android, android-room

I want to store data locally in the android device, and I was reading up on the Room database for that purpose, however I don't know how much data can be saved in the Room database without causing any latency in retrieving/adding data in the application. So how many bytes of data can be stored in the Room database without it affecting the application's performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Room based its [storage around SQLite](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room).

> The Room persistence library provides an abstraction layer over SQLite to allow for more robust database access while harnessing the full power of SQLite

Therefore, the next logical question would be, how huge can SQLite content stored in Android. [This documentation provide insight](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#getMaximumSize()):

> public long getMaximumSize () Returns the maximum size the database may grow to.

There's also this [limit from SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html). As for what happened when we hit that limit, I guess android will raise [SQLiteFullException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteFullException.html).